# How do you pick out the ith matrix in a n-dimensional matrix?

Tags: matlab

For the sake of argument, let's say I have this 3 x 3 x 2 matrix:

```
A = [5 7 8; 0 1 9; 4 3 6];
A(:,:,2) = [1 0 4; 3 5 6; 9 8 7];
```

And I'd like to pick out the first matrix (dimension: 3 x 3 x 1), how do I do it?

Comment: `A(:,:,1)` if I'm not missing anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, already in the comments, is:

```
A(:,:,1)
```

Longer answer:

You can pick out any (hyper)-rectangular subset of a matric by simply specifying the elements you want per dimension, weather there are 1, 2, 3, 4 or more dimensions in the array. In short:

1. Each dimension is specified, in order. Dimension 1 is specifies row, dimension 2 specifies column, dimensions 3 and up are not usually visualized, so just represnt 3 and up
2. For each dimension you can specify one of the following: a) A single index number, b) A vector of index numbers, or c) a logical vector the same length as the dimension you are selecting from d) `:`, which represents all elements in this dimension.
3. Per dimension specifiers are ANDed together, resulting in a (hyper)-rectangular array.

For example, using your `A` array:

```
A = [5 7 8; 0 1 9; 4 3 6];
A(:,:,2) = [1 0 4; 3 5 6; 9 8 7];
```

- To subset the first matrix you need: all of dimension 1 ":", all of dimension 2 ":", and the first element of dimension 3 "1". Therefore:

  ```
  A(:,:,1)   %Returns      5     7     8
  %                        0     1     9
  %                        4     3     6
  ```
- To get the first and third columns of the second page, use:

  ```
  A(:, [1 3], 2)  %Returns      1     4
  %                             3     6
  %                             9     7
  ```
- To get all rows which end in 9 from the first matrax, you can use:

  ```
  mask = A(:,3,1)==9;  %Returns logical [0; 1; 0];
  A(mask, :, 1);       %Returns [0   1   9;
  ```